# Facebook FQL Question

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to use the Facebook Javascript API to run FQL queries, and it works fine if I try and get users by username or uid, but doesn't work when I'm searching by name.

```
function get_username()
{
    var name = prompt("Enter name: ")        
      FB.api(
      {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT username FROM user WHERE name in "'+name+'"'
      },
      function(response) {
          var x = response[0].username
        alert('Username is ' + x);
      }
    );
}
```

I realize that this will probably return multiple users, but I can't figure out how to tell if it's returning multiple users or no users at all, it seems to freeze after trying to get response[0].username.

I'm probably making a beginner mistake but any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

I don't see a username field.  I think that's the issue.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and you're probably right that it was an issue, but unfortunately it doesn't work any better if I search for something that's definitely there like uid.

Comment: Can you use IE 8 or firefox with firebug and put a debugging point there, right before you run that code, and evaluate it?  Just have it return name (which is indexable, so it should be searchable by name).

Comment: Good idea.  I'm getting an Error 102, "Session key invalid or no longer valid" the Facebook error code page (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Error_codes) is not very helpful.  When I search by username though it is just returning the proper info, what about searching by name could be triggering an invalid session key?

Comment: That is very odd... I'm not sure, that could be the sign of a bug...  alternatively you could try using the users_get rest method and querying the user information that way too...  I've not run into this one, so unfortunately, can't be much more help.